# How too put multiple hyperlink inside one td using angular mat-table where it should redirect to respective mentioned link

Tags: angular, hyperlink, angular-material, mat-table

If I put  a `,` character  in between two links (let's say [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) , [www.test.com](http://www.test.com)) inside one td or column cell in mat-table angular material, in that case that should redirect to their respective pages or details. How can I achieve it?

Note: I can't use more than 1 `<a>---</a>` because it will impact if any link doesn't have comma , .

Comment: Can you put a sample piece of html together? I'm not clear on what you are looking to do. Are the links inside the td like `<td> www.example.com, www.test.com</td>`?

Comment: code, link can have values in array like "www.example.com , www.test.com", so what is happening with below code is, "www.example.com , www.test.com" treated as single hyperlink.But i want it to be two seperate hyperlink when i hover to it. <ng-container matColumnDef="link">
            <th class="col-color" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Link
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let usersList" >
              <a href (click)="onNavigate(usersList)" target="_blank" >
                {{usersList.link }}
              </a>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

Comment: @AndyDangerGagne Please have a look at my comments above